# GMP-Assembly code?

Tags: assembly, gmp

Where i can find ASSEMBLY code for my program written for gmp-5.0.0
im using UBUNTU  and G++ compiler..
command for compiling the code is "g++ test.cc -o outp -lgmp"

actually i want to know what happens internally in terms of 1's and 0's...
how the memory allocation will takes place and how the operations will performed on RAW bits!!

Answer (score 2):

The GMP package contains a `mpn\` folder which contains all assembly code for GMP. Please, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125823/gmp-arthimetic-operations/70400147#70400147) but, in short, all GMP high level functions (like `mpz_...`, `mpq_...`, and `mpf_...`) call the `mpn_...` functions for operations on natural numbers. These "low-level" functions actually call highly-optimized assembly code written for a great deal of platforms (x86, ARMs, sparcs, powerpcs, etc.), and the decision on which specific code to link is done by the GMP Autotools (Autoconf and Automake) system according to your target platform. The code there in `mpn\` dir is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: The GMP repos have asm sources for the functions (https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/x86_64 is the mpn/x86-64 subdirectory), with various versions tuned for different microarchitectures.  Kind of a rats nest under x86-64 with subdirectories for uarches and for "fastavx", so not obvious where the best version for any given CPU is.  But yeah, definitely read the commented asm source, not disassembly.

Comment: @PeterCordes, love the *rats nest* stuff, it's why GMP is a winner, I'm bewildered every time I think of how much time they spent feeding those lovely *Several Species Of Small Furry Animals Gathered Together In A Cave And Grooving With A Pict* :)

Answer (score 1):

From the `gcc(1)` man page:

```
   -save-temps
       Store the usual "temporary" intermediate files permanently; place
       them in the current directory and name them based on the source
       file.  Thus, compiling foo.c with -c -save-temps would produce
       files foo.i and foo.s, as well as foo.o.  This creates a
       preprocessed foo.i output file even though the compiler now
       normally uses an integrated preprocessor.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the generated assembly language using the `-S` flag. Keep in mind that this will mostly contain the assembly generated for *your* code, not the generated code for things like library functions you use. The "mostly" is because it can/will include code generated for inline functions in headers you've included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `objdump`<sup>[1](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=o/objdump)</sup> to disassemble your `libgmp`. It won't be interesting.

(And the disassembly of your code mostly just include a call to the `libgmp` function which won't reveal "what happens internally" unless you disassemble `libgmp` as well.)

Perhaps you want to read the source code<sup>[2](http://gmplib.org:8000/)</sup> instead?

Answer (score 0):

The code is written in C so you should look at the source code this will be a first step to understand the assembly code (usually it is enough to understand what happen with "raw bits"). There is some assembly inlined anyway

Then maybe what you could do is to run your code inside gdb and use the `disassemble` command to see the assembly code of a very few and specific peace of code and try to understand them.